# How do I move a block to the top of the sidebar?

Tags: blocks, xml, magento2.2.3

I have created a block in the backend of Magento and using the below code added it to the category page-

```
<page>
 <body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="category.description" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="filteredby">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">filteredby</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

The image shows up, but it shows up at the bottom of the container. So I tried moving it in that file with this code-

```
<move element="filteredby" destination="sidebar.main" before="-"/>
```

and it didn't work. So I tried the same code in my default.xml and in my catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml. I cleared the cache everytime after I made the change and still nothing. Am I not placing the code in the correct place or is the code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this one :

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="filteredby">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">filteredby</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
 </referenceContainer>
 <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="sidebar.main" after="filteredby"/>
```

Comment: Still no go, but I found the answer. Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: I have tried and it's working fine, I think there is some another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the block to move. I was using the wrong template. I was using the one from blank, not Luma. Once I switched those I was able to just insert the image at the top of the layered navigation.